# Golang select trigger

Tags: go

I am working on the GoLang Tutorial 
[Select.go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5)

```
func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

For the 2nd case statement, I understand that it will be triggered when something comes through the *quit* channel.
But I don't understand why the 1st case statement will be also triggered. It is just plainly pushing into pipe. It does not look like some "wait-and-trigger" scenario.
More broadly, what are the criteria to judge if the case statement is triggered?

Comment: Read the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)

Comment: stackoverflow does not want me to delete the question...

Answer (score 0):

In this case it *looks* like some "wait-and-trigger" scenario. One can send in unbuffered channel only when receiver side of pipe can receive. Unbuffered channels are like rendezvous. So `c <- x` can't proceed before `fmt.Println(<-c)` done with print and ready for receiving new value.
In case of many possible choices case is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. So the criteria to judge is just a probability. If many goroutings want to send or receive from a channel, then perhaps it would be triggered rather then rare case.